# Problema ao usar iframe SecurityError

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Boa noite,
Possuo um sistema de formulário, e meu cliente deseja colocar o formulário no site dele.

A equipe dele me solicitou um iframe para implementação nos portais e web-sites porém quando fiz um teste apresenta o seguinte erro:

> SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://meucliente.meudominio.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

O iframe, está em um arquivo teste.html que está rodando em localhost, toda requisição Ajax funciona somente quando dou um submit em um form que isso ocorre.

Alguém sabe como poderia resolver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá não sei o porque isso aconteceu mas resolveu meu problema.

Esse erro só acontecia quando eu tentava dar um typeof dentro do meu beforeSend no ajax.

> Modifiquei para o script abaixo e agora funciona:

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    try {
                        parent.systemForms.beforeSend();
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.log("WARNING >>>", "systemForms.beforeSend not exists!");
                    }
                    return xhr;
                },
```

> Antes (quando dava o erro):

```
beforeSend: function () {
                    if(typeof parent.systemForms != 'undefined') {
                          parent.systemForms.beforeSend();

                    } else {
                          console.log("WARNING >>>", "systemForms.beforeSend not exists!");
                    }
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

Você deve usar o [CORS](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), o servidor que está recebendo deve enviar de volta o seguinte cabeçalho HTTP.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: seudominio
```

Se for servidor `Apache` basta seguir [estas instruções](https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html).

Comment: Olá Lucas, já tentei fazer uso do CORS. Não é ele o problema, é alguma coisa no iframe security, sandbox algo assim.

Comment: Nem é feita uma requisição HTTP do tipo "Options" para analisar o mesmo.

Comment: @HiagoSouza você poderia explicar melhor sobre o teste.html estar em localhost? O submit dele no caso faz uma requisição para qual domínio?

Comment: olá lucas obrigado, mas já localizei o problema. A Solução encontra-se na resposta que deixei.